# Disable Enter Button only when focus is not in textbox

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I'm trying to develop a webapp, using Master Page in different pages of my project.
I need to avoid the pression of the Enter Button, because I can't control what happens (I don't know where the focus is).
So I've added the following code

```
<body  onkeydown="javascript:EnterKeyFilter();"> 

  function EnterKeyFilter() {
       if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
       event.returnValue = false;
           event.cancel = true;
       }
   }
```

And it works! If I accidentally press the Enter button nothing happens, and that's exactly what I was looking for!

The problem is that I need to use the Enter button when I'm writing something in any textbox that I have in my pages. not in a particular one, in any textbox I have.
I'm pretty new to Javascript, so please forgive me if the question is silly, but is there any chance to accomplish what I ask ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.activeElement.tagName
```

to get the tag of the currently focused element; you could use

```
document.activeElement.tagName == 'INPUT'
```

for example, hope this helps.

Comment: this is not working... maybe because I'm using asp:textbox  in my code ?

Comment: Try using INPUT or TEXTAREA